# Store checked/filled objects in a string for each panel

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, panel, parent

My program generates dynamic a specific amount of panels with checkboxes / textboxes. In next step, I want store them in a csv file with ";" as Delimiter.
But firstly, i have to create the string for each panel. I tested the following with the checkbox:

```
foreach (object cb in ((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Controls)
{
    if (cb is CheckBox)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)cb).Checked)
        { str1 += ((CheckBox)cb).Text + "1;"; }

        if (!((CheckBox)cb).Checked)
        { str1 += ((CheckBox)cb).Text + "0;"; }
    }
}
```

I implemented this already in the CheckBox_CheckedChanged Listener - str1 have the right formating, but when I click on another panel the string gets overwritten.

**How can I store them seperatly for each panel?**

In the next step, I want the foreach loop outside of the CheckedChanged Listener, but then I have no sender, to the get parent information.

[image]

Comment: *store them in a csv file* - store whom? `Text`? *outside of the CheckedChanged Listener* - where? Show us concrete code with exception/problem among the lines.

Comment: Are all the panels/checkboxes in the same form? Personally I'd make a usercontrol for one panel, (which exposes its own CSV functionality). Otherwise you could use store each csv inside the Tag property of  each panel, but that would be considered somewhat hacky.

Comment: You should be able to loop over those controls. They are sitting in some Parent and you can loop its Controls collection.. You are doing it ok, but why in a cheng listener? Is that what you want? When do you want to do it??